# Как прикрепить кнопки к push notification?

Tags: java, android, уведомления, android-notification

Погуглил нашел несколько примеров, делаю все как написано, но почему то кнопки не отображаются...

Вот код

```
public static void sendNotification(Bundle extras, Context context) {
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = getStandardPriorNotification(extras, context);
    mNotificationManager.notify((int) System.currentTimeMillis(), mBuilder.build());
}

private static NotificationCompat.Builder getStandardPriorNotification(Bundle extras, Context context) {

    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,
            (int) System.currentTimeMillis(), new Intent(context, UserDataScreen.class), 0);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo)
            .setLargeIcon(icon)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(body))
            .setContentText(body)
            .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .addAction(R.drawable.logo, "Last", getee(context))
            .addAction(R.drawable.logo, "Last", getee(context));

    return mBuilder;
}

private static PendingIntent getee(Context context) {
    Intent maybeReceive = new Intent();
    maybeReceive.setAction("CUSTOM_INTENT");

    Bundle maybeBundle = new Bundle();
    maybeBundle.putInt("userAnswer", 3);//This is the value I want to pass

    maybeReceive.putExtras(maybeBundle);
    PendingIntent pendingIntentMaybe = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 12345, maybeReceive,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    return pendingIntentMaybe;
}
```

Я ожидаю увидеть 2 кнопки под `push notification`, но они не показываются...

Что делаю не так?

Comment: Это баг, связанный с тем, что кнопки не отображаюся, если телефон подключен через usb к компу. Попробуйте получить нотификацию, с выдернутым шнуром

Comment: Без разницы... Ничего не поменялось. Но я подключил другой телефон и все заработало... Очень странно, что на одном работает, на другом нет...